# Is GWT (Google Web Toolkit) have any feature which is look like jquery-select2?

Tags: jquery, gwt, jquery-select2

I am working on a GWT Project, where I want to implement a multiple select box option, which can easily done be jquery-select2 multiple select feature.

Is there any feature or widgets by which I can do the similar job ?

Answer (score 2):

GwtChosen is a good option, inspired by jQuery Choosen makes a pretty customizable and user friendly selector boxes. https://github.com/ArcBees/gwtchosen

Comment: Thanks (@
Ignacio Baca)...it seems...gwtchosen.. is what I need for now.